# Add Tensorboard server to Flask endpoint

Tags: python, flask, tensorboard

I have a Flask App and a Tensorboad server. Is there a way by which I can map the Tensorboard server to one of the endpoints of Flask so that as soon as I hit that endpoint it triggers the Tensorboard server?

Flask application

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello-world', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def say_hello():
    return jsonify({'result': 'Hello world'})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host=host, port=5000)
```

Tensorboard server code:

```
from tensorboard.program import TensorBoard, setup_environment
def tensorboard_main(host, port, logdir):
    configuration = list([""])
    configuration.extend(["--host", host])
    configuration.extend(["--port", port])
    configuration.extend(["--logdir", logdir])

    tensorboard = TensorBoard()
    tensorboard.configure(configuration)
    tensorboard.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    host = "0.0.0.0"
    port = "7070"
    logdir = '/tmp/logdir'
    tensorboard_main(host, port, logdir)
```

I tried creating an endpoint in Flask app and then added `tensorboard_main(host, port, logdir)` in the hope that if I hit the endpoint then the server will start but I got no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that to integrate a TensorBoard server into a larger Flask app, the best way would be to compose the applications at the WSGI level.

The `tensorboard.program` API allows us to pass a custom server
class. The signature here is that `server_class` should be a callable which takes the TensorBoard WSGI app and returns a server that satisfies the `TensorBoardServer` interface.

Hence the code is:

```
import os

import flask
import tensorboard as tb
from werkzeug import serving
from werkzeug.middleware import dispatcher

HOST = "0.0.0.0"
PORT = 7070

flask_app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@flask_app.route("/hello-world", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def say_hello():
    return flask.jsonify({"result": "Hello world"})


class CustomServer(tb.program.TensorBoardServer):
    def __init__(self, tensorboard_app, flags):
        del flags  # unused
        self._app = dispatcher.DispatcherMiddleware(
            flask_app, {"/tensorboard": tensorboard_app}
        )

    def serve_forever(self):
        serving.run_simple(HOST, PORT, self._app)

    def get_url(self):
        return "http://%s:%s" % (HOST, PORT)

    def print_serving_message(self):
        pass  # Werkzeug's `serving.run_simple` handles this


def main():
    program = tb.program.TensorBoard(server_class=CustomServer)
    program.configure(logdir=os.path.expanduser("~/tensorboard_data"))
    program.main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiprocessing here: create one process for flask and another for tensorboard, then run it on the same host.

Code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from tensorboard.program import TensorBoard
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


def tensorboard_main(host, port, logdir):
    configuration = list([""])
    configuration.extend(["--host", host])
    configuration.extend(["--port", port])
    configuration.extend(["--logdir", logdir])

    tensorboard = TensorBoard()
    tensorboard.configure(configuration)
    tensorboard.main()


def flask_main(app, host, port):
    return app.run(host=host, port=port)


@app.route("/hello-world", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def say_hello():
    return jsonify({"result": "Hello world"})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    host = "0.0.0.0"
    port_for_tensorboard = "7070"
    port_for_flask = "5000"
    logdir = "/tmp/logdir"
    process_for_tensorboard = Process(target=tensorboard_main, args=(host, port_for_tensorboard, logdir))
    process_for_flask = Process(target=flask_main, args=(app, host, port_for_flask))
    process_for_tensorboard.start()
    process_for_flask.start()
    process_for_tensorboard.join()
    process_for_flask.join()
```

If you want that inside flask endpoint tensorboard will be show some things, then you need to look at shared data from one process to another (think it would be more complicated than this example)

Comment: I already have the code which runs both the service on different ports but on the same host. But I want a way by which I can add the Tensorboard server to Flask endpoint.

Comment: @lokesh If you just want to add the Tensorboard server to a Flask endpoint, why not just use an HTTP redirect?

Comment: I tried using reverse proxy but I was not getting the correct output.